# Custom home page not recognized by system

Tags: theming

I have set up a Drupal 8 site with a custom home page using page--front.html.twig. The content displays at domain.com/front. When I go into Administration to change to the new home page, it says that the path is invalid. I've also tried leaving the field blank.

[image: Path is invalid]

I also noticed that when I'm on /front, the browser tab displays "Page not found".

I've cleared the cache repeatedly (and every time it sends me to /user/1).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues at play here, which is where you are getting confused.

1) `page--front.html.twig` - this is a template suggestion for the `page` theme hook. This can be seen by the double-hyphens that follow `page`. The `page` theme hook is used to wrap the content of every page on the site, using the `page.html.twig` template. Drupal's theme layer allows for creating suggestions for templates that take precedence over the base template. In this case, when on the front page, the site looks for `page--front.html.twig`, and if it finds this file, it uses it. You have created this file. However, you'll notice I said this template wraps the current page content. That leads to:

2) Page content. 'Pages' on Drupal show content if a page has been assigned to the given path. However, if a user goes to a path that doesn't exist, they get the 'page not found' page. This page is wrapped by `page.html.twig`, just like any content page.

When you go to /front, you see page not found, because you have not created a page at that path yet. You've only created a template for the front page, whatever that may be (even if that ends up being page not found).

You can test this by creating a new node, and setting the path to be `/front` (note - you'll need appropriate permissions for this). Then set the site front page to `/front`, and your template will be picked up.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying. Thank you so much for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a clear homepage, then you can use the [Empty Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_page) module. Just create a page with the module, add the URL to page in the Site Information settings and define a template in the theme.